# Is there any function to use with list to jump next line?

Tags: java, arraylist, filewriter, file-read

Trying to read text file & adding content to an array list and than writing to a new text file but its not appearing in the same format as of original file.
I want it to be in same format as of original file.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\amank\\eclipse-workspace\\DataStructures\\src\\sample1-pp.txt")); 

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //testing
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter ("C:\\Users\\amank\\eclipse-workspace\\DataStructures\\src\\output.txt");; 

    if(!sc1.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println("File is empty");
    }

    try {
        while (sc1.hasNext())
        {

            list.add(sc1.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\p{P}", ""));


        }
        sc1.close();    

        //for testing

        for(String str: list)
        {
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
```

### Expected

Pride and Prejudice

by Jane Austen

Chapter 1

It is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single man in possession of a good fortune, must be in want of a wife.

======

### Actual

pride and prejudiceby jane austenchapter 1it is a truth universally acknowledged that a single man in possession of a good fortune must be in want of a wife

Comment: So you're converting to lowercase and stripping characters and wondering why that's what's being written? Or you're wondering why you skipped over the part of the `nextLine` docs that say the line separator isn't included in the string? Or what?

Comment: You probably want to use: `writer.write(str + "\n");`

Comment: Your issue is clearly with regards to the presence of `toLowerCase()` and `trim()` which as the name of the functions suggest, converts the characters to a lowercase and trims away excess whitespaces.

Comment: I am reading the file which I mentioned in "Expected " and I want to remove all punctuation's, integers and convert all uppercase to lower case and write that in a new file in the same way as present in the original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add line seperator while writing to the file

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\amank\\eclipse-workspace\\DataStructures\\src\\sample1-pp.txt")); 

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//testing
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter ("C:\\Users\\amank\\eclipse-workspace\\DataStructures\\src\\output.txt");; 

if(!sc1.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println("File is empty");
}

try {
    while (sc1.hasNext())
    {

        list.add(sc1.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\p{P}", ""));


    }
    sc1.close();    

    //for testing
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    for(String str: list)
    {
        writer.write(str+newLine);
    }
    writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why You read lines from files, convert them to lowercase, trimming them then add them to ArrayList...?
Just add lines to the ArrayList as is

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\amank\\eclipse-workspace\\DataStructures\\src\\sample1-pp.txt"));

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        //testing
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\amank\\eclipse-workspace\\DataStructures\\src\\output.txt");;

        if (!sc1.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("File is empty");
        }

        while (sc1.hasNext()) {

            list.add(sc1.nextLine());

        }
        sc1.close();

        //for testing
        for (String str : list) {
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```